# vb.net Input Box Function

Tags: vb.net

I am using an input box. In tat am getting the number as input. When the user presses OK the program is workin. But when I press the cancel button am getting a error message

" Conversion from String "" to 'Integer' type is not valid "

If i press cancel I need the program to end.
and also i want to know how to move to other form when i press cancel in input box

Comment: Please paste your code here. thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its probably a good idea to use try parse for these situations it handles more cases than empty strings for example non numeric characters characters

```
Dim number As Integer
Dim result As Boolean = Int32.TryParse(inputBox.Text, number)
if Not result Then
    number = 0
End If
```

Answer (score 1):

If user didn't enter anything in the input box and press cancel, it will be an empty string. Your system won't be able to convert an empty string to integer. Therefore, your program should handle this scenario with code similar to below.

```
If inputBox.Text = "" Then 
    inputValue = 0
Else
    inputValue = inputBox.Text
```